# Change the Default Target Server for Entity Framework Code First Approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to apply my code first migrations directly to SQL server or Azure Database instead of using the Default .sql server or Localdb/mssqllocaldb.. is there a way to do this from web.config and without editing code in context class?

Comment: Change the connection string ?

Comment: After changing the connection string its still not connecting to Azure db and going back to Localdb/localmssqldb only.